# Internal Server error in input field when typing String < string as input data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I tried to enter string < string in an input field which will accept any string it shows an Internal server error(example:abcd < abcde). How can I solve this issue.
What the reason behind this??I tried String < digit-string format it actually works

Comment: Use HTMLEncode.

Comment: I don't exactly imagine you reproduce that. You mean it happened when you submit some data to server?

Comment: Yes it happens when submitting the data

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @NikhilNarayanan please share the code what you tried and where exception occurs, it will help to someone provide solution.

Comment: @DarkKnight Thanks. HTMLEncode works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTMLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.